# The help center is in another castle: Are link only help center articles allowed?

Tags: discussion, help-center, link-only-answers

I recently saw [this help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising) that was link only. [[Screenshot in case it gets deleted]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA1YQ.png). Its content was:

> Find out more about advertising on Stack Overflow by visiting
> https://business.stackoverflow.com/advertise.

If that was posted as an answer, it would have been flagged down as NAA or VLQ and would have been deleted promptly. But since it's a help center article, we can't flag or even downvote them.

Are these types of articles allowed? What is the recommended course of action for these?

Comment: Well, the bigger problem is that the link doesn't actually work - at least not for me. It just shunts me to the SO front page.

Comment: @Catija Should I report that as a bug?

Comment: Not necessary. I already fixed it.

Answer (score 12):

In general, I understand your question and why you're asking it - and it's a reasonable question. For most things we wouldn't do this. We don't say "this page is empty but go look at this FAQ instead" for example. The Advertising help center page, though is... essentially just a redirect or a disambiguation page or a stub - take your pick.

I contemplated adding more to it when I edited the link to the current page just now but I was overly concerned that I'd be editing it to duplicate the current content that the Ads team who controls the actual Advertising page might change at some point in the future, leaving the help center incorrect or confusing.

In this specific case, there's not much value that can be added without risking the page becoming outdated other than just pointing people to the actual product page for advertising, which doesn't rely on our Q&A editor to create, so it has much nicer formatting than anything the help page itself could manage.

Yes, it's somewhat concerning that the existing link got broken but, in all likelihood, if the URL broke again, the content on the page would also be outdated.

Comment: Is it not possible to just add an auto-redirect to the redirect rules to avoid this page altogether? I doubt this is "your department" so to speak, just a thought

Comment: It's unclear to me whether it's possible or not - it'd certainly require some dev work, though.

Comment: yeah, most likely - usually it is just a redirect rule (although I am not intimately familiar with how SE's backend is set up), though, so should not take much effort. That would help clean things up by simply skipping the page